# where to see your pass type identifier from ipa?

Tags: ios6, ipa, entitlements, passbook

Is there a way to view your app's pass type identifier from the ipa? I am having trouble where my ad hoc build works fine, but once I submitted the app to the app store, PassKit stopped working for apps that were accessed on the device. I don't want this to happen again, so I opened up the `.ipa` file and tried to find the `pass-type-identifier` in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file, but nothing was there.

Stranger still, when I archived, XCode made a `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` file and within it I could see my pass type identifier clear as day. When I turned this archive to a `.ipa`, however, the rest of the entitlements still showed up in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file but the `pass-type-identifier` was still missing.

I was wondering if anyone else managed to find a way to do this?

Thanks,